# How to set up Pylint to only do some inspections

Tags: python, pylint

I'm trying to set up Pylint to only do certain inspections and no others, e.g. only check for W0601 and W0612.  I've tried using an `enable=` line the the `[MESSAGES CONTROL]` section of my pylint.rc but that doesn't seem to do what I want.

I'm using Pylint 0.25.1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like a bug with the way rc files are parsed.

Order matters on the command line (undocumented?) so you need to disable first then enable:

```
pylint xyz.py --disable R,C,W,E --enable W0601,W0612
```

**But this is not reflected correctly with `--generate-rcfile` and does not work with `--rcfile` ...these are probably bugs. Like [#36584](http://www.logilab.org/ticket/36584).**

In the rc file with the disable line, all messages get disabled, even with disable before enable like on the command line.

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=R,C,W,E
enable=W0601,W0612
```

Answer (score 14):

In Pylint >= 0.27 there is a new `--disable=all` option

`pylint --disable=all --enable=W0201`

or

`pylint -d all -e W0201`

You can put it in rc file but as *aneroid* points out there is a bug still that means you cannot then enable any messages, except from command line, so:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=all
```

then

`pylint -e W0201`

would work.

Answer (score 1):

@aneroid: you may be right that there could be order issue in generating/reading the configuration file; and also that the fact that order matters on the command line should be documented. I've planified and commented the ticket you refer to accordingly.

@peter-graham, so your probably have to use the command line to achieve this until the #36584 ticket is fixed. I would recommend :

```
pylint --disable-all --enable=W0601,W0612
```

Comment: Pylint gives me 'no such option' if I try to use `--disable-all`.   `pylint --disable=I,C,R,W,E,F --enable=W0601,W0612` works though.

Comment: `--disable=all` instead of `--disable-all`